# SQL: Is there a difference between these two queries

Tags: sql

Given this data base schema:

[image]

Is there a difference between the following two queries:

```
SELECT NAME, MIN(MOVIEYEAR - YEAR(BIRTHDATE)) AS DEBUT_AGE
FROM STARSIN
JOIN MOVIESTAR ON STARNAME = NAME
GROUP BY NAME;

SELECT NAME, MOVIEYEAR - YEAR(BIRTHDATE) AS DEBUT_AGE
FROM MOVIESTAR
LEFT JOIN STARSIN ON NAME = STARNAME
WHERE MOVIEYEAR IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING MIN(MOVIEYEAR);
```

I think they will return the same result, am I wrong?

Comment: The second should not compile - you need something after `HAVING MIN(MOVIEYEAR)` like `HAVING MIN(MOVIEYEAR) = '2010'`

Comment: Why don't you run them and see what result or execution plan it generates?

Comment: Have you tried running both to see if they return the same results?  What;s the point of turning an `INNER JOIN` into a `LEFT JOIN` with a null check?

Comment: I've executed it and it compiles. I'm not sure if I have data in my database that will produce different results.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @DanielRusev What database server are you using?  I have never seen a system that allows a `HAVING` without an operator.  What is `HAVING MIN(MOVIEYEAR)` supposed to mean?

Comment: @DStanley: My guess is: Daniel is using MySQL which beasically alllows to use any expression as a boolean expression (even if it is none). If the expression can be converted to a number 0 is treated as "false" any number not equal zero is treated as "true". If the expression can not be converted to a number it's treated as "false". A condition like `where 'foobar'` is therefor treated as false. I assume `min(movieyear)` is treated as `false` if the lowest year is zero, otherwise it's true (because > 0 is "true")

Comment: I'm using Web SQL on w3schools site. I think 'HAVING MIN(MOVIEYEAR)' is true if it's not zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your HAVING condition in the second one is incomplete.
The second one also skips any row where Movieyear is NULL which is not handled by the first one (Of course this might be redundant depending on whether Movieyear is Nullable)

Comment: Movieyear is not nullable because it's part of the primary key, so, I think, both queries will skip rows where Movieyear might be null.

Comment: Yep, then there is no need for the WHERE Movieyear IS NOT NULL.

Comment: What about the second HAVING condition, what did you wanted it to do?